# Why do big companies use scammy looking URL's?

Tags: email, url, scam

Why do big companies like microsoft use URL's like buy.live.com, that don't look like they belong to microsoft at all?

Is there a technical reason not to use something like buy.live.microsoft.com ?

Funny looking URL's like the above one make it really easy to scam a user that is more willing to click some unkown link, than to cross check it on the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question. Mostly it has to do with branding and trademarks.

Comment: Well, I could rephrase it to say "Should a company use a URL that looks scammy?" or "Should a company always make clear affiliation in the url". Or as a question about best practice for companies wanting to keep their customers secure. Maybe the question is generally too broad or opinion based.

Comment: yeah, but even then it might end up as a really opinion-based question, or one with a de facto "of course" answer. Of course companies should have consistent communication with their customers to prevent confusion (and phishing), but that ends up being a UX, trademark, and branding issue, not really a security issue. The impacts are about security, but the details of the realities are not.

Comment: Marketing & Acquisitions of companies with scam-like URLs

Comment: Big companies with big ideas like to create different marketing identities. They don't think of them as scammy but rather as the "next big thing". This is purely about marketing and sales which is the core of companies like Microsoft and Apple far more than tech and security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify the certificate authority for live.com, and verify that it is by microsoft. These url's are branding, not scams. They may sometimes expect you to be familiar with the brand name live, but if not, your best course of action is to either check the certificate (SSL), or WHOIS lookup the domain & google search to verify its integrity.